# Prompt in select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my application in user registration I have a country picker..

```
<%= select(:user, :country, options_for_select(@COUNTRIES)) %>
```

And I want to add a prompt as a first default value (something like "--- select country ---"). Where and how should I put this option?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use the FormHelper `:prompt`

```
select(:user, :country, options_for_select(@COUNTRIES), {:prompt => "--select county--"})
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper

Answer (score 7):

```
collection_select(:product,
  :category_id,
  Category.all,    
  :id,    
  :title,    
  {:prompt => true}
)

collection_select(:product,    
  :category_id,    
  Category.all,    
  :id,    
  :title,    
  {:include_blank => 'Please Select'}
)
```

both of these result in the same html, but the first one will not include the 'Please Select' option when you return to edit the previously created Product

Answer (score 4):

You can also give customized prompt value like this

```
select(:user, :country, options_for_select(@COUNTRIES), :prompt=>"select User name")
```

Comment: How can I set value to prompt option, by default it's " ", what if I want a 0 value for that

Answer (score 2):

Very simple:

```
select(:user, :country, options_for_select(@COUNTRIES), :prompt=>true)
```

For the prompt "Please select", or this for your custom text:

```
select(:user, :country, options_for_select(@COUNTRIES), :prompt=>"Select country")
```

Also note that `@COUNTRIES` is wrong, an instance variable should be lowercase - `@countries`, a contant would just be `COUNTRIES`.