# Prompt text not working in options_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I can't seem to get this prompt text to show, despite it seemingly being constructed exactly as my others are. What am I overlooking? Thanks for any help!

**This one doesn't work**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= form.label :role %>
  <%= form.select :role, options_for_select([["University Staff", "staff"], ["Private Clinician", "clinician"]]), {prompt: 'Please Select Your Role'}, { class: "form-control" } %>
  </div>
```

**This one does**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :university %>
    <%= form.select :university_id, options_for_select(University.all.map{ |uni| [uni.name, uni.id] }), {prompt: 'Please Select Your University'}, { class: "form-control" } %>
  </div>
```

Comment: This link is for using a select tag but have you tried implementing it using `:prompt => 'Your text here'`.  For reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668658/prompt-in-select-tag

Comment: Can you tell why one would work and not the other?

Comment: So I'm not 100% sure why one would not work and the other would.  I think has to do with some of the "magic" that is done behind the scenes for you when you pass in a mapping of a list of models vs hard code values.  Unfortunately I'm not a Rails expert so I can't speak to this but maybe a more senior Rails individual could comment on it and explain.

Edit: Maybe this link to the docs will get you going down the path of finding the explanation? https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select

Comment: Thanks - it also wasn't working when it was options_for_select from a model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was advised to create a user model class method for selecting the role, and this somehow allowed the prompt to work.